# AWS CloudFormation:Subnet has different VPC Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to create an Aurora DB instance using a CloudFormation script. It [requires me to have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722394/rds-with-cloud-formation-and-az-issues) subnets with 2 availability zones. I entered 2 subnets which have different AZs, but now I get this error in the stack creation log:

```
DatabaseSubnetGroup: Subnet has different VPC Id: vpc-dd3bf9ba than vpc-e0e11ab7.
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the two subnets, although in different availability zones (AZs) are part of two separate VPCs (logical network isolation). You would need to select two subnets in different AZs but in the same VPC.