# Template error: Cannot use Fn::GetAZs in Conditions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

```
Conditions:
  DBInstanceLaunch:
    IsFirstPrimaryAZ:
      Fn::Equals:
      - !Ref DBAvailabilityZone
      - Fn::Select:
        - 0
        - Fn::GetAZs: ''
```

When I try to upload this, I get "Template error: Cannot use Fn::GetAZs in Conditions"
I checked in the docs, Fn::GetAZs is supported by Conditions.
I am trying to do what is mentioned in this answer: [RDS with Cloud Formation and AZ issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722394/rds-with-cloud-formation-and-az-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked in the docs, Fn::GetAZs is supported by Conditions.

No its **not supported**. `Fn::GetAZs` can [only be used](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-equals) with `Fn::If`, which is not the same as `Conditions` section in CloudFormation.